# Angular2 write on console from template click event

Tags: angular

I wonder whether the following is possible somehow. The question is not limited to `console.info` but all Javascript functions in general.

```
<a (click)="console.info(foo)">click me doesn't work</a>
```

`Cannot read property 'info' of undefined`

It seems that templates can only access component properties, so you have to create an extra function for that inside your `Component`:

```
<a (click)="executeConsole(val)">execute console does work</a>

executeConsole(val) {
  console.info(val);
}
```

With React you can do something like that:

```
<a onClick={() => console.info('it works')}>it works</a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would have to declare a property that can access the console object in the component ts code then call that. For example...

Declare in your component ts...

```
public c : any;
```

In the component constructor set the property to the console object...

```
this.c = console;
```

In your view you can now call info()...

```
<a (click)="this.c.info("Hello world")">click me</a>
```

Comment: Meh, I was hoping there would be something better than this.

Comment: I agree, it would be nice if you could do it without changes to the component ts code.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a service wrapper for your console and inject it in the corresponding components. If you do that in typescript in the constructor, then it can automatically create a public member for you that will be accessible from template, so it will be just a matter of adding it as constructor parameter.

It seems otherwise not possible to have a "global" scope. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37741010/angular2-access-global-variables-from-html-template).

Answer (score 0):

### How to use a global variable in an Angular component.

I know this is old, but I thought this would be helpful. You don't have to create a **wrapper** method. You just have to tell your component about an outside global you would like to use, then map it to your component.

Use the declare keyword:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html

**Just write this in your component.**

```
// Import statements...

declare const console;

@Component({
// Your Component Config
})

export class YourComponentClassName {
    public console = console;
}
```

**Then inside your HTML file can use console like this:**

```
<div (click)="console.info('Hello')"> </div>
```