# Cannot approach Typescript enum within HTML

Tags: html, angular, typescript, enums

I made an enum with Typescript to use in MyService.service.ts MyComponent.component.ts and MyComponent.component.html.

```
export enum ConnectionResult {
    Success,
    Failed     
}
```

I can easily get and compare a defined enum variable from MyService.service.ts:

```
this.result = this.myService.getConnectionResult();

switch(this.result)  
{
    case ConnectionResult.Failed:
         doSomething();
         break;
    case ConnectionResult.Success:
         doSomething();
         break;
}
```

I also wanted to use the enum for a comparison within my HTML using the *ngIf statement:

```
<div *ngIf="result == ConnectionResult.Success; else failed">
            <img src="../../assets/connection-success.png" height="300px" class="image-sign-style" />
</div>
<ng-template #failed>
       <img src="../../assets/connection-failed.png" height="300px" class="image-sign-style" />
</ng-template>
```

The code compiles but the browser gives me an error:

> Cannot read property of undefined

[image]

With the following html indication error line:

[image]

Does anyone know why the enum cannot be approached like this?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You will have to write it in the following way in `.ts` file.

```
enum Tenure { day, week, all }

export class AppComponent {
    tenure = Tenure.day
    TenureType = Tenure
}
```

And now in html you can use this like

```
*ngIf = "tenure == TenureType.day ? selectedStyle : unSelectedStyle"
```

I hope it is more clear now. :)

Comment: Don't forget to use '=' and not ':', between TenureType and Tenure, i.e. assign the type don't define it. I just made that mistake overlooking what @Nikhil had written. +1

Comment: Simple easy solution. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 298):

The scope of the template is limited to the component instance members.
If you want to refer to something it needs to be available there

```
class MyComponent {
  public get connectionResult(): typeof ConnectionResult {
    return ConnectionResult; 
  }
}
```

In the HTML you can now use

```
*ngIf="connectionResult.Success"
```

See also [Angular2 access global variables from HTML template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37741010/angular2-access-global-variables-from-html-template/37742209#37742209)

Comment: Since I am strictly following the coding standards, what data type , I have to give for the connectionResult

Comment: I don't know. I only used TypeScript in Plunker and there were no type checks. I'd expect the error message tells you the expected type when you use an incompatible one, doesn't it?

Comment: Thanks, let me start a new conversation in stack overflow

Comment: Yes, just a plain property member didn't work for me, but setting it as a getter worked.

Comment: Not as in [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56182063/521554) that you can keep the name. (might create other problems though, ones I have not discovered yet)

Comment: @NasrulBharathi The return type will be `typeof ConnectionResult`.

Comment: None here with this error? `error TS2475: 'const' enums can only be used in property or index access expressions or the right hand side of an import declaration or export assignment or type query.`

Answer (score 62):

You can just add the enum to your component as property **and use the same name** of the enum (Quarters) in your templates:

```
enum Quarters{ Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4}

export class AppComponent {
   quarter = Quarters.Q1
   Quarters = Quarters //here you are creating a variable/alias to the enum
}
```

In your template

```
<div *ngIf="quarter == Quarters.Q1">I=am only visible for Q1</div>
```

The reason why this works is that the new porperty is basically of this type:

```
TileType: typeof TileType
```

Comment: If you want to output the name of the enum, like in a `div` or `mat-icon` you have to reference the enum, and not the item directly. Easier to show than explain: `<mat-icon svgIcon="{{Quarters[Quarters.Q1]}}"></mat-icon>`

Comment: this is definitely the cleanest way

Comment: This option is way better than others...

Comment: Why do I get: `This condition will always return 'false' since the types <enum values> have no overlap.`?

Answer (score 22):

```
import MyEnum from enums;
```

.... Declarate var ....

```
public myEnum = MyEnum;
```

and in html use:

```
<div *ngIf="xxx === myEnum.DATA"> ... </div>
```

Answer (score 8):

In your Service

```
export enum ConnectionResult {
    Success,
    Failed     
}
```

Assign the enum to a varaible in TypeScript File

```
ConnectionResult = ConnectionResult;
```

Then read your Enum from HTML as bellow

```
*ngIf="result == ConnectionResult.Success"
```

Answer (score 4):

Most common mistake coders do while using enum if they want to use it in html files they declare like below which is often overlooked.

```
  myEnum : MyEnum
```

Please notice that its not colon(:), instead an assignment operator has to be used like below:

```
myEnum = MyEnum
```

Just now sat with my colleague to solve this issue , and it took half an hour to debug this because of just one char (using : instead of =).

Answer (score 2):

You can bind as text if enum defined as below (those values won't enforce a json string value coming from API)

```
  export enum SomeEnum {
      Failure = "Failure",
      Success = "Success",
  }
```

In .ts file

`public status: SomeEnum;`

In .html

`<div *ngIf="status == 'Success'">`

**Another way, tested in Angular 8+ is to have enums with numbers**

```
  export enum SomeEnum {
      Failure = 0,
      Success = 1,
  }
```

In .ts file

`public status: SomeEnum;`

In .html

`<div *ngIf="status == 1">`

Comment: I believe all enums come with numbers automatically

Comment: You can believe what you want but I tested it and thus provided 2 approaches. So no, if you don't specify a number it does not come with a number like in C#. This could behavior may be subject to TypeScript version (+ maybe Angular frx version)

Comment: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-enum

Answer (score 0):

in **component**:

```
 export class LevelsFieldsComponent implements OnInit {
  grades: GradeDto[]; // add enumn in class of Component
  constructor() { }
 }
```

in **html**:

```
*ngIf="gradeId == gradeEnum.Cool"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to declare a type that holds the type of the enum.
example:

```js
export enum Icons {
 Icon1 = 'Icon1',
 Icon2 = 'Icon2'
}
export type IconsType = typeof Icons;
```

Then in the component:

```js
class MyComponent {
  icons: IconsType = Icons;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually declare a variable as the type of enum and initialize it with the enum like this:

```
ConnectionResult: typeof ConnectionResult = ConnectionResult
```

Don't forget to import the enum inside in the component

```
import {ConnectionResult} from "./connectionresult.ts
```