# Enums in templates - This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'RequestStatus.Done' and 'RequestStatus.Rejected' have no overlap

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have html from .  in this form i want to check value for show direfent form .

i set this condation in html :

```
requestStatus = RequestStatus;

<ng-container
    *ngIf="
      (model.lastStatus.requestStatus == requestStatus.Done ||
        model.lastStatus.requestStatus == requestStatus.Rejected)
      else ChangeStatus
    "
  >
```

and  `model.lastStatus.requestStatus` is `number` .

and this is the Request Type :

```
   export enum RequestStatus {
    New = 1,
    Processing = 2,
    Accepted = 3,
    Rejected = 4,
    Done = 5
}
```

but when i run the project it not show me any error and run good .

but when i want to build it show me this error :

> ERROR in src/app/pages/pages/e-money-deposit/components/emoney-deposit-detail/emoney-deposit-detail-request/emoney-deposit-detail-request.component.html(10,16): This condition will always return 'true' since the types 'RequestStatus.Done' and 'RequestStatus.Rejected' have no overlap.

**whats the problem????**

Comment: I have a theory, but first a question - As a test, if you hard code the numbers rather than referencing the enum, does it start working?

Comment: @speciesUnknown no . when use the hard code number it not show me error

Comment: @speciesUnknown  `model.lastStatus.requestStatus == 5 ||
            model.lastStatus.requestStatus == 4`

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045311/cannot-approach-typescript-enum-within-html

Answer (score 0):

Enums are a transpiled feature which don't work very well in templates.

Write an expression on the typescript side of your component.

In the component:

```js
export class WhateverComponent {
  public requestIsFinished() { 
    return (this.model.lastStatus.requestStatus == requestStatus.Done ||
        this.model.lastStatus.requestStatus == requestStatus.Rejected);
    }
}
```

In the template:

```xml
<ng-container 
    *ngIf=" requestIsFinished() else ChangeStatus"
>
```