# Angular: ngIf doesn't recognize enum type

Tags: html, css, angular

this `*ngIf`:

```
<div *ngIf="type === FilterType.DateRangeFilter">
    ...
</div>
```

results in the error

`error TS2339: Property 'FilterType' does not exist on type 'FilterComponent`

even though the enum type `FilterType` is imported into the component:

```
import { FilterType } from '../filter-collection/filter-collection.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter',
  templateUrl: './filter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter.component.css']
})
export class FilterComponent {

  constructor(private type : FilterType) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

from here:

```
export enum FilterType {
  DateRangeFilter, SensorSelectFilter
}
```

Any ideas why this wouldn't work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot approach Typescript enum within HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045311/cannot-approach-typescript-enum-within-html)

Answer (score 5):

Your HTML template doesnt have access to variables declared outside of your component. To resolve this, assign the enum to a variable within your component's scope

```html
import { FilterType } from '../filter-collection/filter-collection.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter',
  templateUrl: './filter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter.component.css']
})
export class FilterComponent {

  constructor(private type : FilterType) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
  
  filterType = FilterType

}
```

and then in your template

```html
<div *ngIf="type === filterType.DateRangeFilter">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the property `type` is used in the `FilterComponent` as `private`, to be able to use it change it to public or create a new one in `FilterComponent` and assign it from the constructor